# Rendering lists react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, optimization, react-native-flatlist

I'm using react native and have parent component with modal. When modal opens, my child component with list rerenders one time, but interface freezing for ~1 or 2 seconds depends on elements in the list. Average size of list is 50 elements. What can be a problem?

```
<View style={styles.screenWrapper}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <List
                onChoose={onChoose}
                flightOffers={paginatedFlightOffers}
                isRequesting={isLoadingOffers}
                isLoadingMore={isLoadMore}
                isLoadingResults={!paginatedFlightOffers.length}
                currency={{ value: searchId?.searchId.currencyRates[body.currency], name: body.currency }}
                showMoreFlightOffers={showMoreFlightOffers}
            />
        </View>
        <NativeModal
            visible={isDetails}
            onClose={onDetailsClose}
            animationType="fade"
        >
            <View>
                <Text>asdf</Text>
            </View>
        </NativeModal>
    </View>
```

Insinde the `List` component there is FlatList and sometimes it writes attention message with advice that I used. Maybe it is possible to avoid rerendering because props in `List` component remains the same. I have tried to use React.memo, but still rerendering exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got answer to this question from my friend and fixed rerendering. The reason `List` was rerendering everytime when modal was opened is that `isDetails` state was changing in the parent component. So everytime state changed my parent component was also fully rerendered.

To fix it I created `isDetail` state in recoil(you can to it throw redux, mobx, context etc.), created new component with modal and in this new component called `isDetail` from recoil.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using flat list as it virtualize list it renders only small batches of elements and more efficient

Comment: Inside a List component there is a FlatList, it doesn't help.